# regular express that checks alpha, spaces and forward slash

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have regular expression in php something like this:

```
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/", "Hello World / How r u");
```

It detects spaces and alpha in string. I want to allow `/` too.

Comment: So, add `\/`, or choose another delimiter then `/` so you don't have to escape the `/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\s\/]*$/", "Hello World / How r u");
```

Test it [here](http://regex101.com/r/gR8jI0/1).

Answer (score 2):

You should use an other delimiter such as #

```
preg_match("#^[a-zA-Z\s/]*$#", "Hello World / How r u");
```